# how to using POST method to pass [object HTMLInputElement] to another php?

Tags: php, forms, post

I want to pass start and end value to data.php using form . Before passing when i print it, it gives me [object HTMLInputElement] .
and from data.php  ,i try to using $_POST['start'] and $_POST['end'] to get the start and end value but get nothing 

code as below ,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/rangeselection">
<style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }   
</style>

 <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js">   
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content">
           <form action="data.php" method="post">
            <h4>Start date:</h4>
            <input id="start" style="width: 100%;" value="" />

            <h4 style="margin-top: 2em">End date:</h4>
            <input id="end" style="width: 100%;" value=""/>
  <input name="" type="submit"  >
          </form>
        </div>
        <script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
                function startChange() {
                    var startDate = start.value(),
                    endDate = end.value();

                    if (startDate) {
                        startDate = new Date(startDate);
                        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
                        end.min(startDate);
                    } else if (endDate) {
                        start.max(new Date(endDate));
                    } else {
                        endDate = new Date();
                        start.max(endDate);
                        end.min(endDate);
                    }
                }

                function endChange() {
                    var endDate = end.value(),
                    startDate = start.value();

                    if (endDate) {
                        endDate = new Date(endDate);
                        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate());
                        start.max(endDate);
                    } else if (startDate) {
                        end.min(new Date(startDate));
                    } else {
                        endDate = new Date();
                        start.max(endDate);
                        end.min(endDate);
                    }
                }

                var start = $("#start").kendoDatePicker({
                    change: startChange
                }).data("kendoDatePicker");

                var end = $("#end").kendoDatePicker({
                    change: endChange
                }).data("kendoDatePicker");

                start.max(end.value());
                end.min(start.value());
            });
        </script>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

but it's nothing .

Would you suggest me any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: i have add my code

Comment: You have to give names to input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `name` attribute in your input elements(`name="start"`,  `name="end"`, `name="submit"`), then you can access their values through  `$_POST['start']` and `$_POST['end']`

```
  <form action="data.php" method="post">
        <h4>Start date:</h4>
        <input name="start" id="start" style="width: 100%;" value="" />

        <h4 style="margin-top: 2em">End date:</h4>
        <input name="end" id="end" style="width: 100%;" value=""/>
   <input name="submit" type="submit"  >
      </form>
```